# Link Category Description

Tags: links, functions

I'm pulling my hair out over this. In the Links manager, you can enter a description for the category (in addition to the link itself). However, in wp_list_bookmarks, there is no way to call this value anywhere. So how can I get it?

I know it's in the term_taxonomy table, under link_category. So is there a function that could be written to retrieve this value dynamically (i.e. not having to declare each link category independently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, with the help of a friend I was able to get this done. I ditched the wp_list_bookmarks and went with a combination of get_terms and get_bookmarks.

```
function blogroll_page( $args = array() ) {
    if(is_page('blogroll')) {
        if( $terms = get_terms( 'link_category', $args = array('exclude' => 16) ) )
        {
            foreach( $terms as $c )
            {
                printf( '<h3>%s</h3>', $c->name );
                printf( '<p>%s</p>', $c->description );

                if( $bookmarks = get_bookmarks( array( 'category' => $c->term_id ) ) )
                {
                    printf( '<ul class="xoxo bookmarks">' );
                    foreach( $bookmarks as $bm )
                        printf( '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>', $bm->link_url, $bm->link_description, $bm->link_name );
                    printf( '</ul>' );

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
get_term_field( $field, $term, $taxonomy, $context = 'display' )
```

e.g.:

```
get_term_field('description', 3, 'link_category')
```

For the bookmarks widget, isn't there an option to show them automatically?

Comment: I think widget deals with descriptions of individual Links and not their categories.

Comment: Hmmm, almost there. it works, but all I'd need to do is write a function to grab the category ID automatically. What I've done is write a string that'll pull every category that they have for a 'blogroll' page, list them in category order with the appropriate header. All I need now is to make it so it recognizes each category.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution for this case, but you can use it for now:

```
<?php $cat = get_category(YOUR_CATEGORY_ID, 'ARRAY_A'); ?>
<?php echo $cat['description']; ?>
```

Hope that helps. I am seeking a better solution. ;)

Comment: yeah, this would pull the regular post category descriptions, not the link category descriptions. Thanks though.